# Two trains ABC and PQR are moving with equal speeds in opposite directions relative to a platform observer. Special relativity problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

[image][image]Observers B and Q stand at the midpoints of their trains. A flash of light E1 is emitted when A and P coincide and another E2 when C and R coincide. The platform observer sees both flashes at the same time but B sees E1 first and then E2 whereas Q sees E2 first and then E1. From the explanation I've been given I understand that B is moving towards E1 so sees it first and that the opposite works for Q. However, isn't this explanation using what the platform observer expects Q and B to see. How do I know, from B's perspective, that it sees E1 first? I've been told that B sees E1 first but I can't picture it from B's perspective.

I hope this makes sense and there's enough information there so that it can be answered...

Comment: A diagram would help.

Comment: Please provide a diagram showing the positions of all of the observers, locations and events that you mention, or project them into our minds by some form of extra sensory psychic communication, because otherwise we would just be guessing.

Comment: I've added some diagrams. Hopefully this means I can save my finite powers of physcic communication for another day.

Comment: Cheers, Theo! You read my mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your very helpful diagrams correctly, all three of the observers are moving relative to each other, and the flashes occur when the ends of the trains coincide. Importantly, we are told that the two flashes are simultaneous in the frame of the platform and occur when all three observers are at the same x coordinate, which for ease of reference I will label x=0.

So, if that is true, then the light from the two flashes will meet at the position of the observer on the platform, ie at x=0. By the time the light from each end arrives at x=0, observers B and Q will be somewhere else. Specifically, B will be off to the left somewhere while Q will be off to the right. That means that B will have seen the light from left hand flash go past to meet the light from the right hand flash at x=0, which in other words means that B will have seen the left hand flash first.

I hope that explains why B has to see the left hand light first if the two flashes are simultaneous in the frame of the platform.

However, you might be left wondering why the flashes are simultaneous in the frame of the platform and not in the frames of either train. The answer is that the trains are both moving with the same speed in the frame of the platform, so they are length contracted by the same amount, so assuming they started off as the same length they will both be the same length in the frame of the platform, which means that their ends will be equidistant from the observer on the platform when they coincide (which is what triggers each flash). By contrast, each train thinks the other train is length contracted, which means that the two ends of the trains can't coincide simultaneously. Observer B will believe that P coincides with A at one moment, and then a little while later R will coincide with C.